# CSS link atribute color

Tags: css

i have faced a problem i could not think a way out.
So I've set some css divs and rules for  attribute.

```
a:visited {
  color: white;
}
```

And I have a div with content which has white/bright background color and I wish to keep it as it is. The problem that links that has been visited in that container are white and impossible to read.
I would like to have a:visited rule to be separated (or different color for different divs) is there a way to do that? There a footer container in the bottom which i want to have white option on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create different rules with the right css selectors

```
.container-black a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.container-white a:visited {
  color: black;
}
```

This will select the link inside the container with the class at the beginning

You should definetly check that article: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048?ec_unit=translation-info-language